# How to create a blank opencv frame with white color in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on `python` `opencv` project where I am creating a 2 blank frames of black color like below:

```
left_frame = np.zeros(shape=[400, 400, 3], dtype=np.uint8)  # shape = [H, W]
bottom_frame = np.zeros(shape=[80, 800, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Above is creating black frame. How can I modify above code to make lets say white color frame or any other color frame. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Use `np.full()` instead, and specify a `fill_value` to set the colour. Example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60773104/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Can you give an example

Comment: Or add a colour to your zeroes `blue = left_frame + [255,0,0]`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your frames turn out black is because the RGB scale color for `(0,0,0)` is black.

Since `numpy.zeros()` returns a matrix of `0`s, the resulting color is black.

To fix that, change `numpy.zeros(shape)` to `numpy.full(shape, 1)`.

Because `numpy.full()` returns a matrix filled with a chosen number, you can choose `1` because the RGB scale color for `(1,1,1)` is white.