# How to properly create an blank colored image in numpy (RGBA)

Tags: python, image, numpy, rgba

I am trying to create a **blank, colored Image in Numpy that includes an alpha channel (RGBA)**.

In my quest to find out how to do this, I came to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772938/numpy-create-an-empty-alpha-image?answertab=active#tab-top). However, when I run either example of the SO answer, the *red* appears *blue*, unlike the images shown in the answer.

So, I am wondering what the correct way to do this is **as `uint16`** (instead of `uint8`) and **without the color mix-up**? Is this a bug with Numpy or am I doing something wrong?

My resulting image:
https://i.ibb.co/VVxhDwY/img.png

My code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

size = (128, 256)

blank_image = np.zeros((size[0], size[1], 4), np.uint8)

# Make first 10 rows red and opaque
blank_image[:10] = [255,0,0,255]

# Make first 10 columns green and opaque
blank_image[:,:10] = [0,255,0,255]

cv2.imwrite('test.png', blank_image)
```

Comment: **OpenCV** uses BGR ordering. All other suites use RGB - including PIL which is what I used in the linked answer. You need to swap Red and Blue with **OpenCV**. And if you want 16-bit, you need to use 65,535 rather than 255. And you need to use `np.uint16`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for pointing that out. I do understand that cv2 uses a very strange ordering. However, what I don't understand is that in the other SO answer it seemed to display correctly. Do I need to convert the image RGBA->BGRA before saving?

Comment: O.k That makes sense, I will try flipping Red and Blue.

Comment: Also, I was going to mention that my question had more to do with *how to create a blank, colored RGBA image* (though this has been helpful). For now, I'm just looking for a half-transparent red image.

Comment: Use `[0,0,255,128]` for semi-transparent red with OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. You should probably post all of this put together as an answer for others.

Comment: You're welcome to write it up as an answer and accept it as correct and grab the points, if you would like. Else I'll do it tomorrow as it's getting late here in the UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you link to was using **PIL/Pillow** (which uses conventional RGB ordering) rather than **OpenCV** (which uses BGR ordering). If you want a semi-transparent solid red in 16-bit with **OpenCV**, use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

size = (128, 256)

# Make semi-transparent solid red image
im = np.zeros((*size, 4), np.uint16) + [0,0,65535,128]

# Save to disk
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If instead of `cv2` you use `matplotlib.pyplot`, your code runs perfectly fine (see below) and then you can simply store it with this library already.

[image: Example of your code]

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, using matplotlib is not an option for me. I am needing the image for image manipulation purposes and thus it needs to be saved to the hard-drive. The fact that matplotlib shows it correctly makes me wonder if this is a bug or maybe it needs to be converted?

Comment: Then if you need cv2, as @Mark commented, the channel ordering is in alphabetical order (BGR) instead of the usual one (RBG).